# How can I subset data from a netcdf file?

Tags: r

So I have this netcdf file:

```
1] "file test.nc has 2 dimensions:"
[1] "Time   Size: 216"
[1] "ID   Size: 36"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file test.nc has 1 variables:"
[1] "float Q[ID,Time]  Longname:Q Missval:1e+30"
```

All I want to do is give it one ID (say 100300). And read a particular time period (Say 4 to 20th timestep)

```
library(ncdf)
ncfile<-nc<-open.ncdf("test.nc")
varcomid <- get.var.ncdf(ncfile,varid = "ID")
vartime <- get.var.ncdf(ncfile,varid = "Time")
ndims    = ncfile$var[['Q']]$ndims 
varsize    = ncfile$var[['Q']]$varsize
comid<-which(ncfile$dim$ID$vals == 100300)

start=c(comid,4)
count = c(varsize[1], varsize[2])

dat<-get.var.ncdf(nc=ncfile,varid="Q",start,count)
```

I am not able to finish the logic of the end timestep.

Also, I am getting this error: C function R_nc_get_vara_double returned error

**Diagnosis using comments**

```
start=c(comid,4)
count = c(varsize[2], varsize[1])

dat<-get.var.ncdf(nc=ncfile,varid="Q",start,count)

Error in R_nc_get_vara_double: NetCDF: Start+count exceeds dimension bound
Var: Q  Ndims: 2   Start: 3,27Count: 36,216Error in get.var.ncdf(nc = ncfile, varid = "Q", start, count) : 
  C function R_nc_get_vara_double returned error
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `start=c(4,comid)` and `count = c(varsize[2], varsize[1])`? First dimension is `ID` and the second is `Time`.

Comment: I didn't know it was the other way round than it appears. new to netcdf format...Let me try. Also, how can I include the end time logic. Basically, I want to include time between 4:25 (say)

Comment: You cannot say the end time. The end time is calculated according to start and count: `end = start + count`.

Comment: I am still getting an error. I have added more info in the diagnosis of the question. Also, can I add count=0 since I want the data for only *one* ID?

Comment: In that case, I was probably mistaken. Try `start=c(comid,4); count = c(0, varsize[2])`. What is the value of `comid`?

Comment: 27. let me try again

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work. the error persists. I tried a lot of combinations of numbers. The only thing the works is: start=c(1,1)
count = c(varsize[1],varsize[2])

Comment: It is not the correct file. Range of ID is [1439445 1442283].

Comment: can you just use any ID there please (say 1439445).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
library(ncdf)
ncfile <- nc<-open.ncdf("test.nc")
varcomid <- get.var.ncdf(ncfile,varid = "COMID")
vartime <- get.var.ncdf(ncfile,varid = "Time")
ndims <- ncfile$var[['Qout']]$ndims 
varsize <- ncfile$var[['Qout']]$varsize
comid <- which(varcomid == 1439445)

start <- c(comid, 4)
count <- c(1, varsize[2] - start[2])

dat <- get.var.ncdf(nc = ncfile,varid = "Qout", start = start, count = count)
```

Comment: Thank you. An aside: How can I use this dat in ggplot2? I am having problems plotting it since it is a not a dataframe. I tried as.data.frame, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I can just do plot(dat). But I need ggplot2 for more control